# Can't get custom attribute value magento 2

Tags: magento2, attributes, custom

I have created custom attribute to product called thickness  and i set visible in catalog product to yes but still getting null of this attribute

I am going to store / product and created a new attribute then i set the value of my attribute as below

```
$_product->setCustomAttribute('epaisseur', $namep);
```

and then i called the attribute in my phtml :

```
$epaisseur = $_product->getData('epaisseur');
```

any help please

Comment: Upload your code please.

Comment: I just go to stores/ product and created a new attribute then i set the value of my attribute as below   $_product->setCustomAttribute('epaisseur', $namep); and then i called the attribute in my phtml :  $epaisseur =$_product->getData('epaisseur');

Answer (score 1):

Please try with below code :

```
$_product->setData('epaisseur', $namep);
```

OR

```
$_product->setEpaisseur($namep);
```

I hope its helpful to you.

Comment: i tried and nothing changed still getteing null

Comment: please check $namep, are you getting value or not. if yes than please share your whole function - code.

Comment: yes and i can find the value in db

Comment: try with $_product->setEpaisseur($namep);

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
$value="test";
$product->setEpaisseur(trim($value));
$product->getResource()->saveAttribute($product, 'epaisseur');
```

Comment: i just used sql request and i get  the value but no one of this solution worked for me thanks a lot for your replay MSA